# How can I create an graph for BFS?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main (){


FILE *file = fopen ( "C\\input.txt", "r" );
int i=0, j=0, k=0, s=0;

char *result[10][10];   
char line[100];    
char *value;
char res[100][100];

for(i=0; i<=9; i++){         
    for(j=0;j<=9;j++){
        result[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}

while(!feof(file)){
fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);

    strcpy(&res[s][0],line);
    printf("%s \n",&res[s][0]);
    s++;

    value = strtok(line, ":");
    result[k][0] = strdup(value); 
    printf("NAME: %s\n", value);   

    value = strtok(NULL, ",");
    result[k][1] = strdup(value);

    r=createAdjListNode(result[k][1]);
    insert2(&hdr,r);

    value = strtok(NULL, ",");
    result[k][2] = strdup(value);

    r=createAdjListNode(result[k][2]);
    insert2(&hdr,r);

    value = strtok(NULL, ",");
    result[k][3] = strdup(value);

    if(result[k][3]!=NULL){
    r=createAdjListNode(result[k][3]);
    insert2(&hdr,r);
    }
    if(result[k][3]==NULL){

        continue;
    } 
       k++; 

}
   // THIS PART IS WRONG. I WANT TO SPLIT LIST AGAIN
p=root;      
char *val,*val1;
if(!strstr(&res[0][0],p->courseName)){
    val=strtok(&res[0][0],":");
    val1=strtok(NULL,":");
    val1=strtok(val1,",");
    while(val1!=NULL){
        val1=strtok(val1,",");
    }
}
fclose(file);
showList(&hdr);
```

}

My input file :

```
George     :Math1,Germany,Math2
Elizabeth  :Music,Math1
Sarah      :Science,Math2
Paul       :Math2,Spanish,Science
```

I want to create a graph with lecture names. I write %50 of code . but When I want to create an adjancecy list there is a mistake . I'm stucked.
THIS PART IS WORNG :
I store every line of input file in an array "res". I want to split again and compare my lecture names. If strstr isn't nul , i want to insert  list. How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down a little from 200+ lines of code? You may be better placed to get an answer

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for one problem.

Comment: How shall the _graph with lecture names_ for your input file look? (The lecture names are the vertices in the graph? How is the set of neighbors of a lecture defined?)